# How to find missing application?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have a new phone. The old one died. I want to install all application that I had on old phone. I am 100% I miss one application in google play-my apps.

I may be uninstall it on the old phone due to the lack of space but I want to find it back.

I do not remember name and I am not able to find it on the google play (may be it was removed).

It was application for training brain, there was a few categories of games: at least 3 version of memory matrix, some games to match previous, 2 version of the of the follow number sequence. (All brain training application are really similar.) For some unknow reasons I have it associated with cat (It must be in name or there was a cat icon on main screen or something like that).

Please give me a tip how I can find this missing application.

Comment: Have you looked into "[Your app](https://play.google.com/apps)" section in Google play?

Comment: Yes I look there. I was not able to find it there. I am using same google account. I was told that google play shows only the application that can be install on current phone so I check it both from my phone and from website on my laptop.

Comment: Try finding it here: [Playboard: Brain Training](http://playboard.me/android/channels/54c41797ea9e19dd390a9868). And search by screenshot here: [Appbrain: Brain training](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=brain+training&src=header).

Comment: It was https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bpi.master.coach.memory&hl=cs Its old icon was http://www.avgo.com/images/best-free-mind-game-app/mind-game-app-5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign into playstore webversion(https://play.google.com) with the same account that you have configured in the old phone and visit the apps page https://play.google.com/apps. This will list all the apps that you have installed using the old phone. Once you configure your new phone with the same account you device will be listed in the list of devices and you can select the new device and install it to install the app on your new phone. [Read More..](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410?hl=en-IN)

Comment: I try this and I do not find it there.

Comment: Are you signed in with the same google account you have configured in your old phone?

Comment: Yes I am using same google account

Comment: Do you see your apps listed in `My Apps` list under the Play store app with the email id configured in the new phone same account as your old phone?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same google-account on your new device as you did on the old one, you should find all the apps you installed in the past at the following website:

https://play.google.com/apps

If you don't use the same account, log into the old one before you visit that website.

Comment: I try this and I do not find it there.